# Set and Get Nested List Element into a single list

Tags: java

I want to set some elements in an ArrayList as this format.
[ 1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7, 8], 9]

And I also try to get elements from the above format and it should convert all nested element list into a single element list.
e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Currently, I am trying to set elements in my list.

```
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> intList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    intList.add(3);
    intList.add(4);

    intList2.add(6);
    intList2.add(7);
    intList2.add(8);

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.addAll(intList);
    list.add(5);
    list.addAll(intList2);
    list.add(9);
```

After execution of above code in debug mode. I checked the list and it's storing element as this [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] instead of this [ 1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7, 8], 9].

Comment: don't use `addAll()` when adding the `intList` and `intList2`

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `addAll` method?

Comment: addAll appends all elements from intList to end of list, i.e. list.addAll(intList1) is like individually adding each element from intList1 to end of list

Comment: You need to create nested `List` object that should look like `List<List<Integer>> lists`, and add to it your `list`, `intList` and `intList2`

Comment: I changed my addAll() method into add() method and now my list storing the elements in this format [ 1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7, 8], 9].

Comment: you need to maintain input order or need the sorted list? i will suggest go for recursive @ManishVerma

Comment: @Deadpool i need sorted list.

Comment: check my updated code, first combine everything into single list and then sort it @ManishVerma

Comment: @Deadpool thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

`addAll()` method just add items from parameter list to origin one one by one. So you need regular `add()` method:

```
...
list.add(intList);
list.add(5);
list.add(intList2);
...
```

Then if you want to convert it to single list you can use stream `flatMap` method. Note: since you have `List<Object>` casting is needed:

```
List<Integer> collect = list.stream()
      .flatMap(o -> {
          if (o instanceof ArrayList)
              return ((ArrayList<Integer>) o).stream();
          return Stream.of((Integer)o);
      })
      .collect(toList());

System.out.println(collect);
```

Or use `List<List<Integer>>` instead of `List<Object>` how it was mentioned in comments. Then the second part will be more concise

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of list from `List<Object>` to `List<List<Integer>>` if you want to operate on Integers, and then add List of Integers to list instead of single Integer, to access create a stream out of list and flatMap.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList();
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList();
List<Integer> intList2 = new ArrayList();

intList.add(3);
intList.add(4);

intList2.add(6);
intList2.add(7);
intList2.add(8);

list.add(Arrays.asList(1));
list.add(Arrays.asList(2));
list.add(intList);
list.add(Arrays.asList(5));
list.add(intList2);
list.add(Arrays.asList(9));

List<Integer> flatList = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
```